# Unable to resolve super class could'nt find class

Tags: android, jar, classnotfoundexception

Iv recently made an android library project and a demo app to use the library and everything was  working fine. But now that I've exported the library as .Jar and now when i try running the application it throws error as

```
01-04 16:03:23.762: W/dalvikvm(4032): Unable to resolve superclass of     
Lcom/applesaucev/sync/SyncInit$1; (1286)
01-04 16:03:23.762: W/dalvikvm(4032): Link of class 
'Lcom/applesaucev/sync/SyncInit$1;' failed
01-04 16:03:23.762: E/dalvikvm(4032): Could not find class
```

'com.applesaucev.sync.SyncInit$1', referenced from method
    com.applesaucev.sync.SyncInit.init

```
01-04 16:03:23.762: W/dalvikvm(4032): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 
1307 (Lcom/applesaucev/sync/SyncInit$1;) in Lcom/applesaucev/sync/SyncInit;

01-04 16:03:23.762: D/dalvikvm(4032): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x002c

01-04 16:03:23.762: W/dalvikvm(4032): Link of class 
'Lcom/applesaucev/sync/SyncInit$1;' failed

01-04 16:03:23.762: D/dalvikvm(4032): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 
0x2567 at 0x2e in Lcom/applesaucev/sync/SyncInit;.init

01-04 16:03:23.762: W/dalvikvm(4032): Unable to resolve superclass of  

Lcom/applesaucev/sync/Requests$2; (1286)
01-04 16:03:23.762: W/dalvikvm(4032): Link of class   
'Lcom/applesaucev/sync/Requests$2;' failed
```

Iv exported the jar in all possible ways, and all the ways iv came a crossed stack-overflow. But I just don't know why the classes are not visible to app
Can anyone tell me what is happening